# why strcmp or strncmp not working on c programming language?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char name[20];
    printf("Whats your name: ");
    fgets(name,20,stdin);
    printf("hello, %s", name);
    if(strcmp(name, "john")==0){
        printf("hello john.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

im a java developer an newly in C . why strcmp not working. help me please

Comment: Welcome to SO. What does "not working" mean? What input do you provide, what output do you expect and what output did you get?

Comment: `strcmp` is case-sensitive, in case you're inputting 'John' or something like that

Comment: Did you take into account that `fgets` will store the newline character in the buffer? See [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html)

Comment: i means in output when i write john , i don't see any hello john print

Comment: You probably mean, when you input `"john\n"`

Comment: Gerhardh thank you bro. you made my way easier

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `fgets`.
Fix the new line bug:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int fixedFgets(char str[], int n);

int main() {
    char name[20];
    printf("Whats your name: ");

    if (fixedFgets(name, 20))
    {
        printf("hello, %s\n", name);

        if (strcmp(name, "john") == 0) {
            printf("hello john.");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
    Function will perform the fgets command and also remove the newline
    that might be at the end of the string - a known issue with fgets.
*/
int fixedFgets(char str[], int n)
{
    int success = 1;

    // Check that fgets worked
    if (fgets(str, n, stdin) != NULL)
    {
         str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        success = 0;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `fgets` fails?

Comment: Thank you very much. GOOD LUCK

Comment: From the docs: "*If the stream is
       at end-of-file [...] fgets() shall return a null pointer.*" IF  the user just pressed Ctrl-D (UNIX) or Ctrl-Z (Windows) EOF is set.

Comment: ... which in turn mean nothing is read into `str` and this `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;` would invoke undefined behaviour and the program in the best case would just crash.

Comment: The same would happen if input to the program had been redirect to an empty file. All in all  `fixedFgets()`  is good example how exactly ***not*** to do it, namely *not* to check the outcome of a relevant function call.

Comment: Thanks for your point. You can add a simple `if (fgets(str, n, stdin) != NULL)` @alk

Comment: *I* know this, but *you* give bad advise to the world. Please you fix your proposal.

Comment: And in any case another call to `ferror()` is strongly recommended if `fgets()` returned `NULL`, to exactly distinguish between EOF and an error.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much @alk

Comment: The last change makes things even worth as the caller has no clue if the string passed in has successfully been set or not.